# Rotate images using CSS and Discard the edges

Tags: css

i have been stuck in this for 3 days now !
I have this image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnFuH.jpg
and i want to rotate it using css.
it's easy to rotate i know, but when i rotate i don't want the edges to be shown
something like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/conWO.png

so how is it possible to do this using css ??
because i have a php loop which displays the images, and i want to rotate them.

Comment: give us some code. and yes CSS can do that with the right HTML structure to clip parts of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include image within a container to hide/clip `overflow`ing parts of image and **rescale** it,

**or** use a **smaller container** than original size of image. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/armtJ/)**

Comment: this is exactly what i was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how you're currently doing this, but if you use `overflow:hidden;` on the containing element, it should work. See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaqq5/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```